# How to "stack" matplotlib figures

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have 3 matplotlib plots created in the following general manner:

```
fig1, ax = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(20,6))
ax[0].scatter(...)
...
ax[1].plot(...)
ax[1].axhline(...)

fig2, ax = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(20,6))
ax[0].scatter(...)
...
ax[1].plot(...)
ax[1].axhline(...)

fig3, ax = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(20,6))
ax[0].scatter(...)
...
ax[1].plot(...)
ax[1].axhline(...)
```

I would like to "combine" `fig1`, `fig2`, and `fig3` into one "figure" object that I can call by name and plot together, e.g. a 3x2 figure.

Comment: Is something stopping you from doing `plt.subplots(3,2)`?